# Laravel PDO class not found

Tags: laravel, pdo

I'm in the Stage of deploying my laravel project on my hosting server .
i uploaded the files and linked them correct ,
But, when i try to access public folder it gives me the error:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php - "Class 'PDO' not found"
```

Configure Command :

```
'./configure' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr' '--exec-prefix=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr' '--bindir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc' '--datadir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share' '--includedir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/include' '--libdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/var' '--sharedstatedir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/com' '--mandir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl=/opt/cpanel/ea-openssl' '--with-openssl-dir=/opt/cpanel/ea-openssl' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-sockets' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-shmop' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/cpanel/ea-libxml2' '--with-system-tzdata' '--with-mhash' '--enable-fpm' '--libdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/lib64/php' '--without-mysqli' '--disable-pdo' '--without-gd' '--disable-dom' '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC' '--disable-opcache' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-xmlwriter' '--without-sqlite3' '--disable-phar' '--disable-fileinfo' '--disable-json' '--without-pspell' '--disable-wddx' '--without-curl' '--disable-posix' '--disable-xml' '--disable-simplexml' '--disable-exif' '--without-gettext' '--without-iconv' '--disable-ftp' '--without-bz2' '--disable-ctype' '--disable-shmop' '--disable-sockets' '--disable-tokenizer' '--disable-sysvmsg' '--disable-sysvshm' '--disable-sysvsem' '--without-gmp' '--disable-calendar' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'target_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu'
```

extension_dir   :

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules
```

- I'm using Laravel 5.5
- my host php version is PHP7.2

Comment: i think it require me to enable it but i don't know how and i'm not sure if it's already installed or not !

Answer (score 0):

I've bolded your issue below.

> './configure' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr' '--exec-prefix=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr' '--bindir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc' '--datadir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share' '--includedir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/include' '--libdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/var' '--sharedstatedir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/com' '--mandir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl=/opt/cpanel/ea-openssl' '--with-openssl-dir=/opt/cpanel/ea-openssl' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-sockets' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-shmop' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/cpanel/ea-libxml2' '--with-system-tzdata' '--with-mhash' '--enable-fpm' '--libdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/lib64/php' '--without-mysqli' **'--disable-pdo'** '--without-gd' '--disable-dom' '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC' '--disable-opcache' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-xmlwriter' '--without-sqlite3' '--disable-phar' '--disable-fileinfo' '--disable-json' '--without-pspell' '--disable-wddx' '--without-curl' '--disable-posix' '--disable-xml' '--disable-simplexml' '--disable-exif' '--without-gettext' '--without-iconv' '--disable-ftp' '--without-bz2' '--disable-ctype' '--disable-shmop' '--disable-sockets' '--disable-tokenizer' '--disable-sysvmsg' '--disable-sysvshm' '--disable-sysvsem' '--without-gmp' '--disable-calendar' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'target_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu'

The reason this flag is problematic when trying to use PDO should be clear.

Comment: I avoid cPanel like the plague, but I'd imagine their docs/support can provide a procedure for enabling PDO.